# Trying to Solve a Riddle of Word Association

Tags: riddle, word

I was given a riddle last week that I have been mulling over for quite a while. The answer to the riddle is apparently supposed to unlock an account of mine that my friend took from me (with my permission, of course).

I would appreciate your help with this.

The riddle is "**Golden name, golden bloom, to perceive, reality.**"

Hint #1:

> The answer is a single word

Hint #2:

> The answer is not a word, but it "resembles" one, whatever that means...

Comment: Please a source for where you got this. A link to a website, for example. Puzzles without attribution will be closed.

Comment: @bobble I literally have no clue where this riddle came from; I was given this riddle verbally from a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after thinking more.

The answer is:

> **Aureal**. Even though it is not a word, it is made up of "aur," the root for words related to gold and golden, hence "golden name, golden bloom." The last part, "real," is based off of the "reality" portion of the association. The "to perceive" is likely to be to throw me off the answer.

Comment: If that is the answer, I think your friend is not very good at making riddles :(

Comment: @Earlien Definitely. He has a long way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer is:

> **Golden flower**. The first part, "Golden name, golden bloom" is quite literal. The term is also the name of a movie about meditation, which may explain  the "to perceive" part. Not sure about "reality" as I have never seen the movie.  (Actually, I think the term "golden flower" is connected to meditation more generally than just this movie, as I have also seen "wellness therapies" companies named Golden Flower.)

Comment: Having spent time grilling my friend, I have gotten the fact that it's a single word. Do you think it could be a specific flower? I tried searching, but I can't find a flower associated with both being golden and perception.